# I am searching for a jQuery or CSS selector for a special issue

Tags: jquery, css, selector

I am searching for an jQuery or CSS selector for a special issue. I do have

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="grid1">
      <p>grids have also p</p>
   </div>
   <div class="grid2">
      <p>grids have also p</p>
   </div>
   <div class="grid3">
      <p>grids have also p</p>
   </div>

   <p>if this p is present, .grid1 should not have a margin</p>
</div>

<div class="parent">
   <div class="grid1">
      <p>grids have also p</p>
   </div>
   <div class="grid2">
      <p>grids have also p</p>
   </div>
   <div class="grid3">
      <p>grids have also p</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is what i have tried:

```
if($('.parent').has('p')){
   console.log(this);
}
```

But i dont know how to trigger this parent, which had p?!

Comment: `if( $('.parent').find('p') ) { $('.grid1').css('margin', 0); }`

Comment: thats cool! i dont have to search for this, jQuery do it for me!

Comment: please find my updated answer for your latest edit fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.parent p').each(function(){
$(this).siblings(".grid1").css('margin', "0px");`
})
```

this should get you all the P elements inside a parent div, and make the div with `grid1` class at the same level margin equal to zero.

Comment: according to your edit, please find my updated script.

Comment: this has done it! but with $('.parent > p').each(function(){…});

Answer (score 3):

```
if(!$('.parent').find('p')){
  $('.grid1').css('margin', '0px'); 
}
```

edit : You can aslo specify an `id` to your parent div, or to your `p` directly, and check if find is `true`

Edit 2 :

I think the code from another guy is good :

```
$.each($(".parent"),function(){
    if(!$(this).children("p").length){
      $(this).find(".grid1").css("margin",'0px')
    }
})
```

Comment: sorry, had forgot that i do have more than one parent div in a site. So how to find and triger $this.parent which had p??

Comment: @Viktor Iterate them.

Comment: thats cool! i dont have to search for this, jQuery do it for me!

Comment: sorry, just one problem more. how to find just p inside .parent but not in its children?!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if($('p').is(':visible')) {
    $(".grid1").css("margin","0px");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple instances of this, you can iterate through each of your `parent` classes and check if it has a `<p>` child using `$(this)`. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/L7sdg/) is a demo.

```
$(".parent").each(function(i) {
    if($(this).children('p').length > 0){
        //<p> is present
        window.alert("<p> is present");
    } else {
        //<p> is NOT present
        window.alert("<p> is not present");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.each($(".parent"),function(){
    if(!$(this).children("p").length){
      $(this).find(".grid1").css("margin",'0px')
    }
})
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uGM77/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you a lot! This is the Version, which works fine

```
$('.parent > p').each(function(){
$(this).siblings(".grid1").css('margin', "0px");
});
```

Thanks to Mohammed ElSayed !!